# Find the database in which a particular record is available

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Consider there are three database say `D1, D2, D3`. And two tables `T1, T2` in each database.

Table `T1` has two columns `C1, C2`. Table `T2` has three columns `C3, C4, C5`.

Now we have six table. The records in each database are different.

**Database structure:**

```
D1:
------
T1  T2


D2:
------
T1  T2


D3:
------
T1  T2
```

**Table strucutre:**

```
T1:
------
C1  C2

T2:
----------
C3  C4  C5
```

I can run the same query in each database, like below, to get the output and find which database has the record:

```
Select * from T1 where C1 = 'Some_value'
```

**The question I have is, how to find which database has the record that I want, without running the query thrice...??**

**Note:** There can be N number of databases with M number of tables in each.

Comment: You have listed mysql, oracle and sql-server tags.  But, you use a term like 'database', and I'm not sure about mysql, but I know for a fact that 'database' means quite different things between oracle and sql-server.  So, what are you *really* asking here?

Comment: In which database? You tagged mysql, sqlserver and oracle?

Comment: seems like you need to read/learn about database sharding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a query like this (SQL Server version below, other dbs are similar):

```
Select 'db1' as db, 'T1' as table from db1.dbo.T1 where 'Some_value' in (C1, C2)
union all
Select 'db1' as db, 'T2' as table from db1.dbo.T1 where 'Some_value' in (C3, C4, C5)
union all
Select 'db2' as db, 'T1' as table from db2.dbo.T1 where 'Some_value' in (C1, C2)
union all
Select 'db2' as db, 'T2' as table from db2.dbo.T1 where 'Some_value' in (C3, C4, C5)
union all
Select 'db3' as db, 'T1' as table from db3.dbo.T1 where 'Some_value' in (C1, C2)
union all
Select 'db3' as db, 'T2' as table from db3.dbo.T1 where 'Some_value' in (C3, C4, C5)
```

Comment: Please see my edit. This might work well for three databases with two tables each. What if 100 databases with 300 tables each.

Comment: @GokulNath Then you would most likely use a dynamic SQL solution specific to the given platform.

Comment: @GokulNath what platform are you using?

Comment: If you want to find a single record in a 100 databases you are doing something very *very* wrong. Please describe the platform and the *real* problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

try this query in oracle, you can use `val` as variable :

```
select Tab1.* from
(Select 'D1' as DataBase,D1.T1.* from D1.T1
UNION ALL
Select 'D2' as DataBase,D2.T1.* from D2.T1
UNION ALL
Select 'D3' as DataBase,D3.T1.* from D3.T1) Tab1,
(select 'Some_value' as val from dual)Tab2
WHERE
Tab1.C1 = Tab2.val;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you need dynamic Sql .
i) first find how many database you hv at that time.
then in each loop create another loop thru all tables of that database and so on.

BTW,what are you trying to do in first place that you will have N no. of database and M no. of tables in each .